# Java Generics: using parameterized interface in method calls

Tags: java, function, generics, interface, abstract

I want to store a function to be applied to any instance of a class. As I want to do this for different classes, I am using an interface in my storing and applying code. But I have some problems with my type variables:

I've got an interface

```
public interface SomeInterface<P>
```

And an implementing class

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface<Object>
```

As well as a handler

```
public class SomeHandler {
   public <R> void someMethod(Function<SomeInterface<R>,R> someFunction) {}
}
```

And the code

```
public void someTest() {
    Function<SomeClass,Object> someFunction = a -> new Object();
    SomeHandler handler = new SomeHandler();
    handler.someMethod(someFunction); //error here
}
```

will not work.

The error at the marked location is "No Instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that SomeClass conforms to SomeInterface"

I already tried to use an abstract class instead of the interface. This did not work either.

I did some research and found a bug including lambda-expressions. Removing the lambda expression did not solve the issue.
Another page hints to a bug in OpenJdk recommending to change the order of the type variables. As I am using the java Function class, I am not able to do this.

I also tried to get the Oracle Jdk, but I am not allowed to do anything on this machine.

Any thought is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function<SomeClass,Object> someFunction = a -> new Object();
```

isn't an instance of `Function<SomeInterface<R>,R>`.

You can either do what [Georg Henkel suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48338400/3788176): to change the type of the `someFunction` variable; or you could just inline the lambda in the method call, and hide the type declaration:

```
handler.someMethod(a -> new Object());
```

Or, to keep your existing type at the call site, change the method signature to:

```
public <R, S extends SomeInterface<R>>
    void someMethod(Function<S, R> someFunction)
```

but note that in order to be able to call `someFunction.apply` with anything other than literal `null`, you will have to pass in a `S` (or something containing a `S`, like a `Collection` or an `Optional`) as an additional method parameter.

If you don't need to call `someFunction.apply` (the question is then why you'd need it...), you can drop the `S` type variable, and just use:

```
public <R> void someMethod(Function<? extends SomeInterface<R>, R> someFunction)
```

Comment: Thank you!
I am skipping the declaration now. As a work around, I used

Function someFunction = a -> new Object();

and had no warning or anything. But I think, skipping the declaration is "nicer".

Answer (score 0):

Change the Function in `someTest()` to:

```
Function<SomeInterface<Object>, Object> someFunction = a -> new Object();
```

**UPDATE** depending on your comment:

You could generalise your handler method to something more of that kind:

```
public <R> void someMethod(Function<? extends SomeInterface<R>, R> someFunction) {}
```

This allows you to use something like the following as Function:

```
Function<SomeOtherClass, MyObject> someFunction = a -> new MyObject();
```

Comment: Yes, this works!
However, this means that all my dispatchers are working with SomeInterface<Object> instead of the different Classes.

So this is my last resort.

Comment: The disadvantage of changing `someFunction` to use `extends` is that you then can't pass anything to it, other than `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and the time you invested!
I am skipping the declaration now as Andy recommends.